Thevenin's theorem and circuit analysis

In this question I have to find the thevenin equivalent, I've tried several methods however none have given me the expected answer. The Thevenin's resistance I found by removing all sources from the circuit and calculating resistance which was (1/140+1/20)^-1+80 = 97.5 ohms.
I attempted to solve the circuit by converting the 1.2 amp source to a 120 V  in series with a 100 ohm resistor then using nodal analysis but that didn't work either likewise attempting to use KCL without converting anything. I also did try converting the 0.8 A current source into a 16V source in series but that wasn't correct either. I'm doing something wrong but I'm not entirely sure what it is.


I'm doing something wrong but I'm not entirely sure what it is

Your first step is sensible and produces this: -

Notice that I've merged the 100 Ω resistor with the 40 Ω resistor because they became in series.
But, why stop at that point. Convert the voltage sources to current sources: -

Then merge the two resistors and two current sources on the left into one current source and one resistor: -

So now, a voltage source, a current source and three resistors have become a single current source and resistor. Next is to convert the newly created current source and parallel resistor into a voltage source in series with one resistor.
That series resistor can then merge with the 80 Ω resistor and you are almost there.
Can you take it from here?

I applied Millman's theorem as shown in the figure. The calculation is simple:

